# Simulating a radio button check command

Tags: winapi

I've been trying to change the state of a radio button programatically:

```
SendMessage(m_hwnd, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_RADIO1, BST_CHECKED), (LPARAM)(hwnd_RADIO1));
```

Why won't this work?

Answer (score 1):

How about using BM_SETCHECK?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775989(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, I tried SendMessage(m_hwnd, BM_SETCHECK, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_RADIO1, BST_CHECKED), (LPARAM)(hwnd_RADIO1)) but i want it to execute the code at case IDC_RADIO1: when i check the button programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [CheckRadioButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761877.aspx) will select the provided `nIDCheckButton` as the active option. It also removes the checkmark from the other radio buttons making up the group.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively one can use the macro

> [Button_SetCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb849167(v=vs.85).aspx)